# Blink Border of Button Jquery

Tags: jquery, blink

I would like to make my button's border blink. But for some reason it's not working.

I am using the code below. Can someone please help me?

```
<input type="button" value="Blinking Button" id="btn" />
```

```
var timer;

function blinking(elm) 
{
   timer = setInterval(blink, 10);
   function blink() { 
           elm.animate({border-color: '#FE642E'}, 1000,  
                   function(){$(this).animate({ border-color : '#424242' }, 1000)                                      });
    });
}
   }

  blinking($("#btn"));
```

[JS Fiddle Link1](http://jsfiddle.net/HKLX7/)

[JSFiddle Link][2]

I am using below code ant it works. But I want to make it simple and can apply this functionality to more than 1 button

```
    var blink = (function() {
    var i = 0;
    var step = 10;
    var up = true;
    var timer = null;

    var next = function() {
        if (up) {
            i += step;
        }
        else {
            i -= step;
        }
        if(i<0){i=0; up=true;}
        if(i>255){i=255; up=false;}
        update();
    };

    var update = function() 
    {
        var btnHighlighted = $('#btnNext');


        if (i%2 == 0) {
            btnHighlighted.css("border-color", '#FE642E');
        }
        else {
            btnHighlighted.css("border-color", '#424242');
        }
    };

    var go = function() {
        next();
        timer = window.setTimeout(blink.go, 30);
    };

    return {
        go: go
    };
   }());
```

Please find the [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/XNV7W/) for above code

Comment: On your JSFiddle I'm clicking the checkbox and the corresponding button is indeed blinking (on Chrome)

Comment: @JoshLiptzin: True, but the OP wants the button's **border** to blink, not the whole thing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p23zn/130/

Comment: Hay Thanks for Quick Reply, I have updated the link. New link is http://jsfiddle.net/p23zn/130/

Comment: Did you see that happen somewhere?  I'm thinking you might have to have a <div> behind the button that is positioned so it looks like the button border and have that blink.  jQuery is applying the animation to the object, not attributes/properties on the object.

Comment: I have updated the post whith the code i currently use. The problem is I am not abel to make it generic so that i can use same code to other buttons.

Comment: I was able to find the solution for the Blinking Button border. Link is http://jsfiddle.net/umw8d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem.

Below is the link for Blinking Button border
http://jsfiddle.net/umw8d/

```
function blink(btn) {
   blink1(btn);
}
function blink1(btn1) {
 //document.getElementById(btn1).className = ;
 btn1.removeClass();
 btn1.addClass("highlight");
 setTimeout(function () { blink2(btn1); }, 750);
}

 function blink2(btn2) {
  //document.getElementById(btn2).className = "highlighted";
   btn2.removeClass();
   btn2.addClass("highlighted");
   setTimeout(function () { blink1(btn2); }, 750);
 }

     blink($('#btn'));
```